# Calculate x y of Point after increasing distance

Tags: java, point

I am trying to get the x and y value of a point after increasing the distance r. Perhaps there is a better way of calculate the angle phi too, so that I don't need to check in which quadrant the point is. The 0-point is at the half of the width and height of the window. Here is my attempt:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

public final class Laser extends java.applet.Applet implements Runnable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7566644836595581327L;

Thread runner;

int width = 800;
int height = 600;

Point point = new Point(405,100);
Point point1 = new Point(405,100);

public void calc(){

    int x = getWidth()/2;
    int y = getHeight()/2;
    int px = point.x;
    int py = point.y;
    int px1 = point1.x;
    int py1 = point1.y;
    double r = 0;
    double phi = 0;

    // Point is in:
    // Quadrant 1
    if(px > x && py < y){
        r = Math.hypot(px1-x, y-py1);
        phi = Math.acos((px1-x)/r)*(180/Math.PI);
    }/*
    // Quadrant 2
    else if(px < x && py < y){
        r = Math.hypot(x-px, y-py);
        phi = Math.acos((px-x)/r)*(180/Math.PI);
    }
    // Quadrant 3
    else if(px < x && py > y){
        r = Math.hypot(x-px, py-y);
        phi = Math.acos((px-x)/r)*(180/Math.PI)+180;
    }
    // Quadrant 4
    else if(px > x && py > y){
        r = Math.hypot(px-x, py-y);
        phi = Math.acos((px-x)/r)*(180/Math.PI)+180;
    }*/
    r += 1;
    point1.x = (int) (r*Math.cos(phi));
    point1.y = (int) (r*Math.sin(phi));
    System.out.println(r+";"+point1.x+";"+point1.y);

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    calc(); 
    g.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point1.x, point1.y);

    int h = getHeight();
    int w = getWidth();
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.drawLine(0, h/2, w, h/2);
    g.drawLine(w/2, 0, w/2, h);

}
/*
public void initPoints(){

    for(int i = 0; i < pointsStart.length; i++){
        int x = (int)(Math.random()*getWidth());
        int y = (int)(Math.random()*getHeight());
        pointsStart[i] = pointsEnd[i] = new Point(x,y);
    }

}
*/
public void start() {

    if (runner == null) {

        runner = new Thread(this);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setSize(width, height);
        //initPoints();
        runner.start();

    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void stop() {

    if (runner != null) {

        runner.stop();

        runner = null;

    }

}


public void run() {

    while (true) {

        repaint();

        try { Thread.sleep(700); }

        catch (InterruptedException e) { }

    }

}

public void update(Graphics g) {

    paint(g);

}

}
```

Comment: Does your attempt work? I'm not sure what your question is exactly.

Comment: Math.atan2 returns an angle in the -pi to pi range, and is intended for Cartesian to polar conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing (x,y) to be r from some other point, when it had previously been some distance r' from that point, correct?  So why not avoid the trigonometry, and just scale each of the components from that point by r/r'?

Edit: ok, iterate over the pixels along whichever component (x or y) is longer (let's assume it's y); for each xi in (0..x), yi = xi*(y/x), and you plot (xi,yi).

Comment: i temporarely uploaded an image here:[link]http://app-zeyynv0x55zn7kqs.apprun4.codenvycorp.com/Ebene_polarkoordinaten.PNG.gif. I want to draw the green lines pixel for pixel started from the randomly generated red points.

Comment: please try this one:http://image-upload.de/file/g0Uj1G/5abb6d9a27.gif ,  if u need a pass its:pppppp

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple! And use `double` variables for such computations, I changed it for you.

```
package test;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public final class Laser extends java.applet.Applet implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7566644836595581327L;

    Thread runner;

    int  width = 800;
    int height = 600;

    Point2D.Double point = new Point2D.Double(400, 100);
    Point2D.Double point1 = new Point2D.Double(405, 102);

    public void calc() {

        double px = point.x;
        double py = point.y;
        double px1 = point1.x;
        double py1 = point1.y;

        double dx = px1 - px;
        double dy = py1 - py;
        double len = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
        double newlen = len+2; 

        double coeff = Math.abs((newlen-len)/len);
        point1.x += dx * coeff;
        point1.y += dy * coeff;


        System.out.println(len+";"+point1.x+";"+point1.y);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        calc();
        g.drawLine((int)point.x, (int)point.y, (int)point1.x, (int)point1.y);

        int h = getHeight();
        int w = getWidth();
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawLine(0, h / 2, w, h / 2);
        g.drawLine(w / 2, 0, w / 2, h);

    }

    /*
     * public void initPoints(){
     * 
     * for(double i = 0; i < pointsStart.length; i++){ double x =
     * (double)(Math.random()*getWidth()); double y =
     * (double)(Math.random()*getHeight()); pointsStart[i] = pointsEnd[i] = new
     * Point(x,y); }
     * 
     * }
     */
    public void start() {

        if (runner == null) {

            runner = new Thread(this);
            setBackground(Color.black);
            setSize(width, height);
            // initPoints();
            runner.start();

        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void stop() {

        if (runner != null) {

            runner.stop();

            runner = null;

        }

    }

    public void run() {

        while (true) {

            repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(700);
            }

            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

        }

    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {

        paint(g);

    }

}
```